Is there any API in Raydium to get the price to token pair?
How can I use the Raydium API to get on chain prices of tokens?

Maybe this example on raydium-sdk-V2-demo can help you: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2-demo/blob/master/src/amm/fetchRpcPoolInfo.ts.
The poolPrice attribute is the price of the token pair.

https://api-v3.raydium.io/docs/#/
you can explore the endpoints of this API, if the mint address is not yet available there, you have to use the pair address to get the price manually on
https://api-v3.raydium.io/pools/key/ids?ids=
